# Sometimes when video is encoded using the Video Toolbox Encoder for web live streaming, the decoder output always has a 4 frame latency

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming, video-toolbox

I am Using VideoToolbox VTCompressionSession For Encoding The Frame in H264 Format Which I will send through web socket to a browser. The Received Frames Will be Decoded and Output Will be rendered in the Website. Now, when using Some encoders the video is rendered always with four frame latency.

How Frame is sent to server :

start>------------ f1 ------------ f2 ------------ f3 ------------ f4 ------------- f5 ...

How rendering is happening :

start>-------------------------------------------------------------------------- f1 ------------ f2 ------------ f3 ------------ f4 ----------- ...

This Sometime becomes two frame latency and Sometime it becomes sixteen frame latency so the usability is getting affected.

Im using this configuration in videotoolbox's VTCompressionSession:

```
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate=3MB
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate=24
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime=true
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel=kVTProfileLevel_H264_High_AutoLevel
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering = false
kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval=1000
```

With Same Configuration i am able to achieve 1 in - 1 out with `com.apple.videotoolbox.videoencoder.h264.gva`. This Issue Is replication with Encoder `com.apple.videotoolbox.videoencoder.ave.avc`

Not Sure if its Encoder Specific. I have also seen that there are difference in VUI Parameters between encoded output of both encoders.

I want to know if there is something i could do to solve this issue from the Encoder Configuration or another API which is provided by the VideoToolBox to ensure that frames are decoded and rendered at the same time by Decoder.

Thanks in Advance....